# Export Room Database File, save the file in files and send when internet available

Tags: android, database, kotlin, storage, android-external-storage

The issue i am having is that, file gets created, i can see in file manager too but when i access it to send it to server, it says "Failed to find configured root that contains /content:/media/external/downloads/153"

I am badly stuck here

Comment: You appear to be trying to pass a `Uri` *into* `FileProvider.getUriForFile()`.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't share your code to clarify the issue.
In general, I think that the problem of your work is in the way of reading the relevant file, which can probably be solved by converting the uri to file path.

Anyway, maybe you can access the created file using [SimpleStorage](https://github.com/anggrayudi/SimpleStorage) library.